# How to find an user on a LDAP server

Tags: c#, ldap

When trying to find an User on a LDAP Server, I get the following error "Unknown error (0x8000500c)"

This is the code I'm using:

```
PrincipalContext domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "gandalf.intrafg");
UserPrincipal p = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "Consultor1");
```

Indidentally, the following piece of code seems to work (no exception is generated), but the samAccountName comes through as a byte array. Anybody knows why?

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://gandalf.intrafg");

DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

//searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenName");
//searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn");
searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samAccountName");

searcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(samAccountName=Consultor1))";

SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();
```

Comment: I have used LDAP queries but I am not familiar with the query you have used. Is your "(&(objectCategory=person)(samAccountName=" =" + UserId + "))" valid?

Comment: Yes, like I said the second block of code works...

Answer (score 0):

Your second code block works just fine, I however did **not** pass the domain name in the DirectoryEntry initializer.

```
    Directory entry = new DirectoryEntry();
//other code
result.Properties["samAccountName"][0].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have should be fine - it works for me, no problem at all.

However: you're not telling us what you fill in for `domain_name` here:

```
PrincipalContext domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain_name");
```

or `userId` here:

```
UserPrincipal p = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, UserId);
```

The `domain_name` **must** be in the "old" NetBIOS style, e.g. `FABRIKAM` - no DNS-style like `fabrikam.com` or AD-style like `dc=fabrikom,dc=com` or even a full LDAP path.

The `userId` must be a valid SAM account name, e.g. max. of 20 chars, letters and numerics only (except for a few valid special chars).

Are you complying with these requirements??

Comment: @bastos.sergio: as I expected - you're not using a proper NetBIOS style domain name - you should be having a domain name such as `GANDALF` or something like that - just a single word, no dots in it - the "old-style" domain name from pre-Active Directory times.

Comment: If I put GANDALF I get the same error as above. If I put INTRAFG I get the error "The server could not be contacted"

Comment: @bastos.sergio: what if you just use `PrincipalContext domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)` - don't specify any domain name. I believe this will pick the current domain your machine is in.

Comment: But my machine isn't in the Domain, doing just that I get the error "The server could not be contacted"

Comment: @bastos.sergio: well if your machine isn't in the domain..... then you cannot create the domain context without specifying a domain user and password ! Try to find an overload where you can define a (domain) username and password.